# disconnect current database connection in controller function and connect another database in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, replication

in my application/config/database.php i have multiple database connections..now currently database connection will be make as per in which city i get logged in.As per the city database connection will be created successfully...now what i have to do is inside a particular function i need to connect a replication database(for only that function i have connected the replication database)...i will connected that replication database connection successfully but the problem is it will connect for throughout my whole application..i need replication database connection for that function only...for rest of the controllers and functions i need to connect the database which i have connected as per the city.

Comment: Which version of CI you are using? Just to check.

Comment: i m using 2.1.4 version of CI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i have come up with the solution of my problem i.e loading the replication database inside the constructor function of model instead of controller's constructor function which allows to load the replication database connection whenever it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem, I believe. By this you can open a connection to replication server and can access both DB servers.

Place the code inside the function where you want.

```
public function replication_test()
{
        echo "<pre>";
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT id FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1");
        $result = $query->row_array();
        print_r($result);
        $db_repli = $this->load->database('replication_db', true);

        $query = $db_repli->query("SELECT id FROM repli_users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1");

        $result = $query->row_array();
        print_r($result);

        // Close the DB
        $db_repli->close();
}
```

Comment: i have tried this but not working....i have closed the connection also but still not working...

Comment: Can you update your question with the code snippet you are using?

Comment: $this->db3=$this->load->database('dbrep',true);
if($this->db3){
        echo "replication db connected";
}else{
        echo "replication db not connected";
 } after this my code is there and at last i have closed the connection i.e $this->db3->close();

Comment: please specify users and repli_users are tables: means in my database the table where my username and passwords are stored ?

Comment: Yes, those are tables. It can be of same name too, thought it would be useful, if it's different names.

Comment: ok.for both print_r($result) i have got the data from replication database...:(

Comment: do i need to close db connection for the regular database ??

Comment: No need to close the regular connection.

What I guess is, either you have the replication db as default one or you have `$db['replication_db']['autoinit'] = true;` in your `database.php`

Comment: its like $db['dbrep']['autoinit'] = FALSE; in my database.php

Comment: Not sure what's happening, there are multiple settings to be checked, DB configuration, autoload, controller etc. The given code is functioning well with multiple applications I've developed.

Comment: ok..all possiblities i have checked...if u find any other way then plz reply...thank u for your time and support :)

Comment: Also make sure that the following is **NOT** set `$active_group = 'dbrep';` in database.php